# Calculate average of n number of days from reference date

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the average of sale in last 5 days of products since the date when there was any change in the product spec.

my 2 dataframes are;

df1:

```
Products Change date
X        10/12/2018
Y        06/12/2018
```

df2:

[image]

Output desired is:

```
Product  Average of last 5 days before change

X        37.6
Y        6
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use pandas [rolling function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to calculate your trailing five period average. Then, because you have your reference date in another data frame you need a join, BROTHER.

```
# calculate rolling 5 period average for all dates
df2 = df2.set_index(['Date','Product'])
df2['ROLLING_AVERAGE_SALES'] = df2.rolling(5).mean()
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop = False)

# Now let's isolate the change dates by joining in the other table
df1['IS_CHANGE_DATE'] = True
df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on = ['Product','Date'],right_on = ['Products','Change Date'], how ='left')

result_df = df3[df3.IS_CHANGE_DATE == True]


# Yeeeeeee boy
print(result_df)
```

This is untested, but it shows you the approach. And dear lord, for humanity's sake... Rename your columns to the exact same thing so they are consistent.